# What to do when a logged in user goes back to the log in page?

Tags: authentication, logout, user-experience

I found three different approaches on various websites that requires a user to log in:

1. Log out a user who goes back to the log in page
2. Redirect the user to a welcome page
3. Do nothing, allow the user to stay on the log in page

I wanted to change the approach from 1 to 2 to improve user experience on my website. But I would like to seek some advice first regarding whether there could be some nasty security exploits awaiting me.

Comment: 1 - completely inacceptable; 2 - acceptable; 3 - makes no sense

Comment: @zerkms, I am not sure, but Gmail seems to allow approach 3, or it could be the cache.

Comment: what's the link to gmail login page?

Comment: @zerkms, mail.google.com

Comment: I go directly to my mailbox, without login page using that link

Comment: How about telling the user he’s already logged in and asking whether he wants to login as a different user?

Comment: @zerkms, sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: @Gumbo, thanks, that could also be an option. What I am more interested to find out is whether there is a security concern. Seems zerkms is implying there is none.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow If you choose option 1, then requesting the login page would virtually have the same effect as requesting the logout page.

Comment: @Question Overflow: you said gmail allows #3. While it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Redirect the user to a welcome page** is a good one..

1 and 3 are not unacceptable for any application

Comment: I understand from the user point of view, I just want to know from a web developer point of view, specific to security.

Comment: @Question Overflow: this question has absolutely nothing to do with security. It is 146% about UX

Comment: @zerkms, thanks. That is what I want to know. Can you put it down as an answer?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow : There is no security problem, If the user is logged then he need not come to login and signup pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user was referred by the "login page"(enters creds). if not and is logged in bounce to safe side. else bounce to public home page

Answer (score 0):

login/register links should not be visible to the user if he is logged in. If we manually traverses to the page by typing the url (ex: www.example.com/login.php) u can put  check on these pages

$_SESSION['userid']!=NULL then redirect to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be best for you if you redirect Logged In user to PREVIOUSLY VIEWED PAGE.

Like -

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="print_HTTP_REFERER" />
```

Then on Login action page - redirect user to HTTP_REFERER using (header or meta refresh)